# Sort Object Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have an object like this:

```
 {
  "name":['John','Bob','Ram','Shyam'],
  "marks":['64','22','80','32']
 }
```

I have to sort the names. After I sort names, marks must be matched according to the names.

When I use sort() function, It only sorts the names. How can I sort my overall object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to alter your data structure to be more sortable. For example:

```js
const data = {
 names: ['John','Bob','Ram','Shyam'],
 marks: ['64','22','80','32']
}

const people = data.names.map((name, i) => ({
  name,
  mark: data.marks[i]
}))

const sorted = people.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

console.log(sorted)
```

A second option would be to keep an array of indexes, which you sort based on the data. This doesn't alter your original structures, but I don't think it is a good option, because it would be hard to keep both the names and marks arrays synced. For example:

```js
const data = {
 names: ['John','Bob','Ram','Shyam'],
 marks: ['64','22','80','32']
}

const index = Array.from(Array(data.names.length).keys())

index.sort((a, b) => data.names[a].localeCompare(data.names[b]))

console.log(index)

// use the names & marks
index.forEach(i => {
  console.log(`${data.names[i]} - ${data.marks[i]}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another key by name `rel` and its value will be an array of objects , where each object has keys by name `name` & `mark`.

While creating this array you can use `sort` function to sort these objects in order

```js
let obj = {
  "name": ['John', 'Bob', 'Ram', 'Shyam'],
  "marks": ['64', '22', '80', '32']
}

obj.rel = obj.name.map(function(e, i) {
  return {
    name: e,
    mark: obj.marks[i]
  }
}).sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))

console.log(obj)
```